# Failing to retrieve a page with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I want to scrape some google page with file get contents function:

```
     $encoded='http://www.google.co.il/#hl=en&biw=1440&bih=799&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:'.urlencode("http://stackoverflow.com/");

    echo  file_get_contents($encoded);
```

When I do this:

echo $encoded;

I get this:

```
http://www.google.co.il/#hl=en&biw=1440&bih=799&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F
```

When I put it in the url.. I get the page that I want

But when I use the function , I simply get the main google page..why does this happen?

Comment: i tested your code, its working for me, google in your language opened

Comment: What do you want to do with a scraped google results page?

Comment: That's not a question; that's a Google request. Also you have not explained what "not working means" in the sense why do you think it *should* work.

Comment: not working means, it doesnt retrieve the page that i want. nice on downvoting , hakra, and voting to close.. u provided no solution..just complaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you url uses googles new **client** side side functionality. Everything after the `#` is for the client, and the server will serve you the content under `http://www.google.co.il/`.

#### update

If you want to use google search results in your program, try using one of their [API for custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). There have been a search webservice for ajax clients under the this url:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=your+term+goes+here
```

It returns results in JSON, the first result is under `responseData->results` array:

```
$search_results = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=your+term+goes+here'), true);
var_export($search_results['responseData']['results'][0]);
```

But i think [this have been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/web-search/) since than (still responds however).

Comment: interesting i didnt know that. How do I overcome that..is there a way to get the page I want ...

Comment: interesting , I dont see the search results however. is it this one: estimatedResultCount

Comment: Added a code example too, still i would recommend you to read upon the custom search api, afaik this endpoint is deprecated since 2009

Comment: hmmm.. I need the number of results: Just after the google search bar: About 31,200,000 results (0.11 seconds)

Comment: It's there in the response, under `responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount` and `responseData->cursor->searchResultTime`.

Comment: hmm.. I thought it would be the same.. but as you can see the figure is lower than 32,200,000.. that is when you go and paste teh url to the page

Answer (score 1):

you can remove # in your URL and use ? then try it

```
<?php
$encoded='http://www.google.co.il/?hl=en&biw=1440&bih=799&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:'.urlencode("http://stackoverflow.com/");

echo  file_get_contents($encoded);
```

Comment: You can get appropriate result try it.

Comment: try my code <?php
$encoded='http://www.google.co.il/?hl=en&biw=1440&bih=799&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:'.urlencode("http://stackoverflow.com/");
echo  file_get_contents($encoded);

Comment: it is almost the solution. I got a page and there was inside the box something like this..site:http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

`$url = "https://www.google.co.in/gfe_rd=cr&ei=RCjlVsPSDPDI8Ae1nruADw&gws_rd=ssl#q=SUCCES"`;

```
echo  file_get_contents($url);
```

gives me Google Page but not the Google search Page ...